# Moving solution files under tfs corrupts binding?

Tags: tfs

I'm relatively new to tfs so I did a mistake, I moved my (already under tfs) source code to another location (moved the solution folder to another destination), the problem is I have changed my source without checking-in my pending changes and now visual studio says that my "solution seems to be under source control but its binding information cannot be fond".
now how can I take my changes and apply it to the tfs(keep in mind that my solution is no longer under tfs binding)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Start by restoring the binding of your solution with source control as described in: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181374(v=VS.100).aspx. If the source control system does not recognize that this solution has been moved after re-binding, add it as a new solution to source control and remove the old solution from source control.

Before performing any of these  actions, always make sure you have a backup of the sources off-line.